# Grouping the data after fetching the query

Tags: sql, sas

I have a problem while regrouping the data from query. I have a dataset like this:

```
PAT_ID MONTH  PRODUCT MOD SEV TOT_CNT
12341  201301 A       1   1   5
12342  201301 B       1   1   5
12343  201301 A       1   0   5
12344  201301 A       0   1   5
```

I am trying to select like in below query:

```
select month,product,sum(mod)/tot_cnt as mod_p,sum(sev)/tot_cnt as sev_p from table X group by month, product;
```

But Its giving output like:

```
MONTH  PRODUCT MOD_P SEV_P
201301 A       0.4   0.4
201301 A       0.4   0.4
201301 A       0.4   0.4
201301 A       0.4   0.4
```

I want only one row. i.e. `201301 A 0.4 0.4`. I have specified group by clause, but it is not working

Comment: Didn't you use `DISTINCT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to distinct your elements like:

```
select DISTINCT month,product,sum(mod)/tot_cnt as mod_p,sum(sev)/tot_cnt as sev_p 
from table X 
group by month, product
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways out of your problem.
The first one was already answered, it's using `Distinct`.
But that's not the most efficient way.

When using `group by` in a `proc sql`, all variables must be either stated as arguments of the `group by` or inside a summary-function (http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002473699.htm).
In your query Tot_cnt was outside the sum() and was causing the rows to appear multiple times. This happens because SAS doesn't know that this variable have the same value in all observations within the same by-group.

So, besides using distinct these are the 2 other solutions that I know of.

1) putting tot_cnt inside `sum`

```
select month, product
, sum(mod/tot_cnt) as mod_p, sum(sev/tot_cnt) as sev_p
from X
group by month, product
```

2) putting tot_cnt inside a `min` or `max`

```
select month, product
, sum(mod)/max(tot_cnt) as mod_p, sum(sev)/max(tot_cnt) as sev_p
from X
group by month, product
```

I'd suggest using 1).